# Unable to get rid of blank screen popping up while scraping content

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, internet-explorer-11

I've created a macro to parse the name of different movies traversing multiple pages from a torrent site. I used `InternetExplorer` in combination with ***Html.body.innerHTML*** parser (usually used with xmlhttp requests) to make the execution faster. Although the content of this site is not dynamic, I used IE to see how it behaves when it does the scraping in combination with ***Html.body.innerHTML***.

> When I run my script using IE, It parses the content as expected and finishes the job. The only problem I'm facing is that there is a blank screen out of nowhere popping up in every pagination like the image below.

***How can I get rid of this blank screen issues?***

My script (no issues when I use `Html.body.innerHTML` in combination with Chrome Driver):

```
Sub FetchContent()
    Const link = "https://yts.am/browse-movies/0/all/action/0/latest?page="
    Dim driver As New ChromeDriver, Html As New HTMLDocument, genre$
    Dim post As HTMLDivElement, I&, R&

    For I = 1 To 3
        With driver
            .AddArgument "--headless"
            .get link & I
            Html.body.innerHTML = .ExecuteScript("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
        End With
        For Each post In Html.getElementsByClassName("browse-movie-bottom")
            R = R + 1: Sheets(1).Cells(R, 1) = post.getElementsByClassName("browse-movie-title")(0).innerText
        Next post
    Next I
    driver.Quit
End Sub
```

I would like to get the same behavior when I try using `Html.body.innerHTML` in combination with IE but it produces blank screens along with the desired result:

```
Sub FetchContent()
    Const link = "https://yts.am/browse-movies/0/all/action/0/latest?page="
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, Html As New HTMLDocument, genre$
    Dim post As HTMLDivElement, I&, R&

    For I = 1 To 4
        With IE
            .Visible = False
            .navigate link & I
            While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
            Html.body.innerHTML = .document.DocumentElement.outerHTML
        End With
        For Each post In Html.getElementsByClassName("browse-movie-bottom")
            R = R + 1: Sheets(1).Cells(R, 1) = post.getElementsByClassName("browse-movie-title")(0).innerText
        Next post
    Next I
    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Blank screen that appears in every pagination in case of `IE` combination with `Html.body.innerHTML`:

[image]

Comment: Use `html.Write ie.Document.body.outerHtml` followed by `html.Close`. Instantiate IE with `Set ie = CreateObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")` and the document with `Set html = CreateObject("new:{25336920-03F9-11CF-8FD0-00AA00686F13}")`.

Comment: It's an immense pleasure to have any sort of solution from you @Florent B.. The thing is I can hardly implement your suggested portion within my script because of my shallow knowledge. However, I appreciate if you mind making this as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I try to test your code with IE and find that I am able to produce the issue.

I find that below line is causing this issue.

> Html.body.innerHTML = .document.DocumentElement.outerHTML

Below is the modified version of your code in which this issue is resolved.

```
Sub FetchContent1()
    Const link = "https://yts.am/browse-movies/0/all/action/0/latest?page="
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, Html As New HTMLDocument, genre$
    Dim post As HTMLDivElement, I&, R&

    For I = 1 To 4
        With IE
            .Visible = False
            .navigate link & I
            While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

            For Each post In .document.getElementsByClassName("browse-movie-bottom")
            R = R + 1: Sheets(1).Cells(R, 1) = post.getElementsByClassName("browse-movie-title")(0).innerText
        Next post
        End With

    Next I
    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Output in IE 11:

[image]

Now, It will not open any blank page in IE.

Comment: I created this post only to learn the usage of `Html.body.innerHTML` in combination with IE. So, keeping this `Html.body.innerHTML` is a must. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like assigning the outerHTML to innerHTML cause this issue. If you want to keep Html.body.innerHTML than try to create MSXML2.XMLHTTP object. Refer first code example in this link. https://codingislove.com/parse-html-in-excel-vba/ Other reference for inner HTML property. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa219842(v%3Doffice.11)

Comment: You are trying to compare the code execution of IE automation with Chrome Driver. Which is not fair comparison here. In IE, You are getting this issue and the above solution can help you solve that issue.

Comment: This is definitely a fair question why one can do while the orher is not until there is a very strong reason. However, ***I'm after that reason***. The way you are trying is help me get the content but for your information I learnt the same couple of years back @Deepak-MSFT. Thanks.

Comment: You are trying to compare the IE automation with Chrome driver. Chrome driver is not a product of Microsoft and it is a third party product. There can be a many differences in the working mechanism of IE automation and Chrome driver. Currently no any information or any documentation available which can tell that why Html.body.innerHTML is not working with IE automation. If I get any document in future than I will try to provide you. Thanks for your understanding.